# register an account and login in java

Tags: java

hi im newbie in java and i try to create a login/registration by using array. but when i try to login the account that i created it always shows out the wrong login details message, am i missing something? or should i use other method to do the validation check other than using array? tq

here's my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter number of account u want to register");

        int n=s.nextInt();

        int regid[]=new int[n];
        int regpass[]=new int[n];

        

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){//for reading id and pass
            System.out.println("enter your favorite user id: ");
            regid[i]=s.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter your password: ");
            regpass[i]=s.nextInt();
            s.nextLine();

        }


        System.out.printf("%-2s %-20s\n", "user id", "password");

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){//for printing all registerted account
            
            System.out.printf("%7d %-20s \n", regid[i], regpass[i]);

        }
        
        System.out.printf("==========================\n");
        System.out.printf("==========LOGIN===========");
        System.out.printf("==========================\n");
        
        System.out.printf("enter your userid");
        String id = s.nextLine();
        
        System.out.printf("enter your password");
        String pass = s.nextLine();

        //user validation
        if(id.equals(regid) && pass.equals(regpass)) {
                   System.out.printf("welcome");
        }else {
                   System.out.printf("wrong id or password");
        }
       

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to get the desired result :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter number of account u want to register");

    int n=s.nextInt();

    int regid[]=new int[n];
    int regpass[]=new int[n];



    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){//for reading id and pass
        System.out.println("enter your favorite user id: ");
        regid[i]=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter your password: ");
        regpass[i]=s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();

    }


    System.out.printf("%-2s %-20s\n", "user id", "password");

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){//for printing all registerted account

        System.out.printf("%7d %-20s \n", regid[i], regpass[i]);

    }

    System.out.printf("==========================\n");
    System.out.printf("==========LOGIN===========");
    System.out.printf("==========================\n");

    System.out.printf("enter your userid");
    String id = s.nextLine();

    System.out.printf("enter your password");
    String pass = s.nextLine();

    //user validation
    boolean logged = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(id) == regid[i] && Integer.parseInt(pass) == regpass[i]) {
            System.out.println("welcome");
            logged = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!logged)
        System.out.println("wrong id or password");
}
```